# Insert string in vector before every string containing pattern

Tags: r

I have the following vector:

```
test <- c("here is some text", "here is some other text", "here is my formula", "2+2", "here is my second formula", "4+4", "here is even more text", "here is my final formula", "6+6")
```

What I'm hoping to do is take every instance of a string containing "formula" and inserting a random string like "CCC" in front of it so that I'd have something like the following:

```
test <- c("here is some text", "here is some other text", "CCC", "here is my formula", "2+2", "CCC", "here is my second formula", "4+4", "here is even more text", "CCC", "here is my final formula", "6+6")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These use only base R:

**1)** Use `append` as shown:

```
test2 <- test
ix <- rev(grep("formula", test)) - 1
for(i in ix) test2 <- append(test2, "CCC", i)
test2
##  [1] "here is some text"         "here is some other text"  
##  [3] "CCC"                       "here is my formula"       
##  [5] "2+2"                       "CCC"                      
##  [7] "here is my second formula" "4+4"                      
##  [9] "here is even more text"    "CCC"                      
## [11] "here is my final formula"  "6+6"
```

**2)** Here are three different one-liners.

The first creates a matrix whose first row contains "CCC" and NA elements and whose second row is `test`.  It then unravels that and removes the NA's.

The second iterates over test outputting the element if formula is not contained in it or a vector "CCC" followed by the element.  This produces a list which is unlisted.

The third prefaces any element containing formula with "CCC\n" and then splits it up.

```
# 2a
c(na.omit(c(rbind(ifelse(grepl("formula", test), "CCC", NA), test))))

# 2b
unlist(lapply(test, function(x) if (grepl("formula", x)) c("CCC", x) else x))

# 2c
scan(text = sub("(.*formula)", "CCC\n\\1", test), what="", quiet=TRUE, sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

Update: Improved code:

```
library(tidyverse)

test %>%
  tibble(value = .) %>%
  mutate(index = row_number(), new_val = ifelse(str_detect(value, "formula"), "CCC", NA_character_)) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(new_val, value), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  pull(value)
```

Here is another approach:
I already mentioned this: For me it is much easier to think in terms of a data frame or a tibble in this situation:

```
library(tidyverse)

test %>%
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(index = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(new_val = ifelse(str_detect(test, "formula"), "CCC", NA_character_)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(new_val, value)) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  pull(value)

 [1] "here is some text"         "here is some other text"  
 [3] "CCC"                       "here is my formula"       
 [5] "2+2"                       "CCC"                      
 [7] "here is my second formula" "4+4"                      
 [9] "here is even more text"    "CCC"                      
[11] "here is my final formula"  "6+6"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(test) %>% 
 uncount(str_detect(test, 'formula') + 1) %>%
  mutate(test = replace(test, duplicated(test, fromLast = TRUE), "CCC"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 1
   test                     
   <chr>                    
 1 here is some text        
 2 here is some other text  
 3 CCC                      
 4 here is my formula       
 5 2+2                      
 6 CCC                      
 7 here is my second formula
 8 4+4                      
 9 here is even more text   
10 CCC                      
11 here is my final formula 
12 6+6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R way with `grepl/cumsum` to create a grouping vector with each group starting at a `"formula"` string. Then `by` will insert `"CCC"` in its place.

```r
test <- c("here is some text", "here is some other text",
          "here is my formula", "2+2", "here is my second formula",
          "4+4", "here is even more text", 
          "here is my final formula", "6+6")

j <- cumsum(grepl("formula", test))
test <- unname(unlist(by(test, j, FUN = \(x) c("CCC", x))))
if(j[1L] == 0) test <- test[-1L]
test
#>  [1] "here is some text"         "here is some other text"  
#>  [3] "CCC"                       "here is my formula"       
#>  [5] "2+2"                       "CCC"                      
#>  [7] "here is my second formula" "4+4"                      
#>  [9] "here is even more text"    "CCC"                      
#> [11] "here is my final formula"  "6+6"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>